# No quarkus-junit5-mockito extension

Tags: quarkus

I would like to mock external API call in quarkus (3.8) test. There is no quarkus-junit5-mockito extension.

I tried to add quarkus-junit5-mockito extension as it is described in official doc (https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client-reactive#mocking-with-quarkusmock). But there is no mockito extension availale so I can not use Mockito.when().

[Quarkus version in doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Apr7O.png)
[Use od mockito in official doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xD0vi.png)

Comment: Here you go https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.quarkus/quarkus-junit5-mockito/3.8.0

Comment: The mockito library is just a library, not an extension. That means it's not can't be installed using some of the handy tools for installing extensions.

Comment: OK, I added it as a dependency, not as an extension. Thank you!